# crontab permission denied error

Tags: linux, cron, permission-denied, rhel6

I put a file.sh for crontab to execute and redirecting the output into an email to my mailox. The script works when I run it manually. Unfortunately, when crontab does the job, it has the following error (from the output sent to me):

```
/bin/sh: /home/zenoss/zen-remote-bkup.sh: Permission denied
```

My crontab setup is the following:

```
30 11 * * * /home/zenoss/zen-remote-bkup.sh 2>&1 | mail -s "Zenoss backup replication" email@abc.com
```

And these are the permission on the file.sh I need to execute:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 zenoss zenoss 1433 Nov  5 10:32 zen-remote-bkup.sh
[zenoss@server1 ~]$
```

Does anyone know which permission I am missing? Thank you.

Comment: How does it work when you run it manually? You must have typed `sh .../remote-bkup.sh` at your shell prompt rather than just `.../remote-bkup.sh`. If you have a different command in your crontab than what you typed on the command line, it shouldn't be surprising that they don't work the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the eXecutable bit on the script to do the job:

```
chmod +x /home/zenoss/zen-remote-bkup.sh
```